# Function for adding object in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I need function like this, but for Phaser.

```
wade.addSceneObject(new SceneObject(dotSprite, 0, dotPosition.x, dotPosition.y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon how I understand your question, I'd highly recommend looking at [a Phaser tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-game) before you go too much further. The official tutorials are really quite good.

Based upon the documentation for WADE I see that [`addSceneObject`](http://clockworkchilli.com/docs/Wade#addSceneObject) adds an object and [`SceneObject`](http://clockworkchilli.com/docs/SceneObject) creates one. So, you want to know how to add a sprite to a game.

In Phaser this would be something like:

```
game.add.sprite(dotPosition.x, dotPosition.y, 'spriteKey');
```

The [Add a Sprite demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/add-a-sprite) shows how to load the image into the cache so it can be included on the page.