# I need something like this, but for Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

i need something for adding object in Phaser, this is something similar but in wade.
wade.addSceneObject(new SceneObject(dotSprite, 0, dotPosition.x, dotPosition.y));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function for adding object in Phaser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565163/function-for-adding-object-in-phaser)

Comment: Reposting a question when you don't get answers is frowned upon here. Especially if you only wait a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Adding objects (usually called sprites) in phaser is super simple. Just load the image in the preloader function

```
function preload() {

    game.load.image('mushroom', 'assets/sprites/mushroom2.png');

}
```

And then add the sprite in the create function

```
function create() {

    //  This simply creates a sprite using the mushroom image we loaded above and positions it at 200 x 200
    var test = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'mushroom');

}
```

Phaser has a ton of documentation on how to do things like this. I got the code from [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/add-a-sprite).

If you are completely new to phaser I highly recommend going through their [tutorial](http://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-game)